# Определить углы ориентации треугольника

Tags: opengles, android, opengl, 3d

Здравствуйте!

Задал такой вопрос на форуме математики:

`Не подскажете, как можно найти углы наклона плоскости, заданной тремя точками, к осям? Т.е. есть три точки (x1,y1,z1), b(x2,y2,z2), c(x3,y3,z3), не лежащие на одной прямой (треугольник). Необходимо найти углы, на которые надо повернуть плоскость (0XY- заданной например тремя точками (0,0,0),(1,0,0),(0,1,0)), чтобы она была параллельна заданному (abc).`

Но, возможно, есть готовое решение в рамках OpenGL ES, android, java, renderscript?

Comment: @Чад, я правильно понимаю, что с наивным решением через синусы-косинусы проблем нет и писать его здесь нет смысла?

Comment: @Etki, я думаю Вы надомной издеваетесь :-) Я уже себе настолько сломал мозг, что рад любым мыслям/решениям по этому поводу :-)

Comment: @Чад ни разу. Сейчас занят, позже постараюсь найти время, чтобы написать-нарисовать, хотя по фату это будет наивное повторение решения с векторами (у меня, в свою очередь, всегда было плохо с векторами).

Comment: @Etki, Буду безмерно рад. Ибо хоть ответ @Дож, даёт понимание, как это применить, чтобы получить нужный результат, самого понимания ещё не наступило. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для начала нужно посчитать нормаль к плоскости:

```
n=[b-a,c-a]/|[b-a,c-a]|
```

Где [x,y] — векторное произведение, |v| — длина вектора.

У плоскости 0XY вектор нормали — (0,0,1), поэтому задача сводится к нахождению поворота, являющегося компизицией поворотов вокруг осей, при котором (0,0,1) перейдёт в n.

Очевидно, что это можно сделать в два поворота вокруг осей (сперва вокруг Y, потом — вокруг X). Для нахождения величин углов нужно спроецировать n сперва в плоскость 0XZ и найти угол между полученным вектором и (0,0,1):

```
AngleY = (n.x,0,n.z)^(0,0,1)
```

Где v^w означает угол между двумя векторами. После поворота вокруг оси Y аналогичным образом вычисляем насколько нужно повернуть вокруг оси Z:

```
AngleZ = (n.x,n.y,0)^(1,0,0)
```

Напоследок: для вычисления угла между двумя векторами полезно знать две формулы для скалярного произведения:

```
(v,w) = v.x*w.x + v.y*w.y + v.z*w.z
(v,w) = |v|*|w|/cos(v^w)
```

Comment: Так, а если немного усложнить задачу:

есть три точки (треугольник) a,b,c, при этом известно что они получены путём поворота последовательно на углы Ax,By,Cz треугольника a',b',c'. Как найти эти углы? Т.е. я так понимаю что 2 угла находятся так как Вы описали, а вот как найти 3тий?

Comment: Мне непонятно: что это за повороты Ax, By, Cz? Вокруг каких осей? От этого зависит, как решать задачу.

Comment: Вокруг осей X, Y, Z.